# significant runtime inflation when using alpha to reduce over-plotting in the R package ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, runtime, alpha

I have a medium-sized set of data I'm trying to visualize, `nrow(df)=7810`. To reduce over-plotting, I've used `alpha=.3` . This has significantly slowed down the time it takes for R to produce the figure. Here are my specs,

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Home
Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3401 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 32.0 GB
System Type x64-based PC
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
ggplot2 version 3.2.1
```

and here's a sample of what's going on,

```
> p <-ggplot(df, aes(x=x))
> t1<-function(){p + geom_point(aes(y=y), shape=4, size=.5)}
> t2<-function(){p + geom_point(aes(y=y), shape=4, size=.5, alpha=.3)}

> system.time(print(t1()))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.14    0.37    0.53 

> system.time(print(t2()))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25   29.69   30.04
```

Does anyone know what's slowing down this script so significantly?

Answer (score 4):

The alpha value alone is not responsible for the slow down. The alpha value combine with the shape seems to slow things down.

Complex vector shapes like the "x" rendered by `shape = 4` seem to substantially slow the rendering time when used with an alpha value. If you are not committed to `shape = 4`, using something like `shape = 16` can speed things up while using the desired alpha values. Example below:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- tibble(x = rnorm(n = 7810),
             y = rnorm(n = 7810))

p1 <- function() {
  p <- ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x, y), shape=4, size=.5)
  print(p)
}

p2 <- function() {
  p <- ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x, y), shape=4, size=.5, alpha = 0.3)
  print(p)
}

p3 <- function() {
  p <- ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x, y), shape=16, size=.5, alpha = 0.3)
  print(p)
}

p4 <- function() {
  p <- ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x, y), shape=22, size=.5, alpha = 0.3)
  print(p)
}

test <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(no_alpha = p1(),
                               alpha = p2(),
                               alpha_circle = p3(),
                               alpha_square = p4(),
                               times = 10)

print(test)
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
         expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
     no_alpha   837.5163   851.7994  1025.0569   910.3687  1173.8753  1403.087    10
        alpha 41456.3393 41708.0781 45831.6033 42589.4998 45219.8180 59578.347    10
 alpha_circle   429.7718   536.9076   719.5507   549.7952   555.9002  1780.282    10
 alpha_square   800.1380   806.5523   882.0163   815.6232   842.4669  1450.395    10
```

EDIT:

We can use `microbenchmark` and `purrr` to see what shapes result in the quickest plotting times.

```r
library(purrr)
library(microbenchmark)

df <- tibble(x = rnorm(n = 7810),
             y = rnorm(n = 7810))

s <- tibble(shape = c(0:24))

plot_fun <- function(shape) {
  p <- ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x, y), 
               shape = shape,
               alpha = 0.3)
  print(p)
}


test_fun <- function(shape) {
  microbenchmark(plot_fun(shape = shape),
                 times = 10)
}

s <- s %>%
  mutate(test = map(.$shape, 
                    ~test_fun(shape = .x)))

s %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(test) %>%
  mutate(time = microbenchmark:::convert_to_unit(time, "ms")) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = shape, y = time, group = shape), outlier.shape = NA) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0:24)) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: timing]

It appears that shape values 0, 1, and 15 through 22 provide faster rendering times than the remaining values.

### Update Feb 2021

I want to update this now that you can select the agg graphics devices in RStudio. I've noticed a quality and performance increase by using this option. Benchmarks are included below using png, agg, and cairo graphics devices:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- tibble(x = rnorm(n = 7810),
             y = rnorm(n = 7810))

p <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y), shape = 9, 
             alpha = 0.3,
             size = .5)

p1 <- function(p) {
  file <- tempfile(fileext = '.png')
  ragg::agg_png(file)
  print(p)
  dev.off()
}

p2 <- function(p) {
  file <- tempfile(fileext = '.png')
  png(file)
  print(p)
  dev.off()
}

p3 <- function(p) {
  file <- tempfile(fileext = '.png')
  Cairo::CairoPNG(file)
  print(p)
  dev.off()
}

test <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ragg = p1(p),
                                       png  = p2(p),
                                       cairo = p3(p),
                                       times = 10)

print(test)
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
  ragg   143.6093   145.6143   147.0587   146.9873   149.2117   150.4617    10
   png 16156.0102 16490.5932 16525.7275 16518.1758 16548.8938 16963.1056    10
 cairo   176.1562   179.4485   181.5183   181.0518   183.5970   188.6689    10
```

The benchmarks show some substantial improvements using ragg or cairo graphics devices. When using the "simpler" symbology, there aren't any substantial improvements.

Comment: And so the plot thickens... How do I distinguish between the _complex_ points and the simple points?

Comment: @BennyBoi We can benchmark how long it takes to make the plots with each shape. See the updated answer.

Comment: This is also an issue if using geom_segment with alpha values